# Replace traceId to another spring

Tags: java, spring

When users resend the application, a new traceId is generated after each attempt to send it. I want to save the first traceId and on repeated attempts enter the saved traceId instead of the new one. So far I can't substitute. Is it even possible to implement such a thing?

Code in application:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TraceRequest {
    private final Tracer tracer;

    public String getTraceId() {
        return tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId();
    }

    public void replaceTraceId(String traceId) {
    TraceContext customTraceId = tracer.traceContextBuilder()
                .traceId(traceId)
                .spanId(EncodingUtils.fromLong(RandomUtils.nextLong()))
                .sampled(true)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi RZF, A Trace ID is considered unique, so storing and replacing it will no longer be a Trace ID. What you are describing, however, is a session ID. You can also add that to your tracing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934834/add-trace-id-and-transaction-id-springboot

Comment: @Reg can I add my own field and put the value there and pass it on?

Comment: Yes - you can; this is known as "Baggage" if you want to google it. Are you using Spring's Sleuth implementation or Micrometer? Maybe add it to the tags, this will help

Comment: I am using Spring Sleuth

Comment: The first SO question I posted shows you how to add values. It is two steps, one add it to the MDC and second adjust your logging to display it. That should do the trick